# Format object with some keys to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

It gets a specific result from my database which I have shown below:

```
const data = {
  short: 'en',
  element: {
    'dsdsea-22dada-2ffgd-xxada-eeee': { name: 'test name', comment: 'test comment' },
    'adad2a-dda13-dsdad-wwwwd-adaxx': { name: 'name 2' },
}
```

And I would like to apply a JavaScript operation to be able to get this result:

```
[
    {
        short: 'en',
        key: "dsdsea-22dada-2ffgd-xxada-eeee.name"
    value: "test name"
    },
    {
        short: 'en',
        key: "dsdsea-22dada-2ffgd-xxada-eeee.comment"
    value: "test comment"
    },
    {
        short: 'en',
        key: "adad2a-dda13-dsdad-wwwwd-adaxx.name"
    value: "name 2"
    }
]
```

I have tried using a combination of Object.entries and the map function, but I don't know how to deal with double keys in a single element object.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far apart from the requirement

Answer (score 2):

This may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective.

It uses [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [template literal using backtick `` characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

**Code Snippet**

```js
const getTransformedArray = obj => (
  Object.entries(obj.element)   // iterate over 'element' key-value pairs
  .flatMap(([k1, v1]) => (      // k1-v1 where v1 is object (with name, comment props)
    Object.entries(v1)          // iterate over v1's key-value pairs
    .map(([k2, v2]) => ({       // map each iteration
      short: obj.short,         // create the resulting object
      key: `${k1}.${k2}`,       // 'key' is created using k1, k2
      value: v2                 // 'value' is v2 as-is
    }))
  ))                            // '.flatMap' used above avoids nesting of arrays
);

const data = {
  short: 'en',
  element: {
    'dsdsea-22dada-2ffgd-xxada-eeee': { name: 'test name', comment: 'test comment' },
    'adad2a-dda13-dsdad-wwwwd-adaxx': { name: 'name 2' }
  }
};

console.log(getTransformedArray(data));
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments in the code-snippet above explain how the code works.

EDIT

Answer updated to use `.flatMap()` as has been highlighted by [@pilchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13762301/pilchard).

Comment: You can use `flatMap()` instead of separate map and flat calls *'It is identical to a map() followed by a flat() of depth 1, but slightly more efficient than calling those two methods separately.'*

Comment: Thank you @pilchard. I need to change my habit. Will edit the answer. :-) Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two loops to iterate over each `element` and then each value of those elements.

Here using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops on the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of each, [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) at each level to apply relevant names to each property, and then creating a compound `key` value using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
const data = {
  short: 'en',
  element: {
    'dsdsea-22dada-2ffgd-xxada-eeee': { name: 'test name', comment: 'test comment' },
    'adad2a-dda13-dsdad-wwwwd-adaxx': { name: 'name 2' },
  }
}

const result = [];
for (const [key, element] of Object.entries(data.element)) {
  for (const [prop, value] of Object.entries(element)) {
    result.push({ short: data.short, key: `${key}.${prop}`, value })
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.keys()` to get the keys in `element`, then map the returned array using the key to access each element object and thus getting the name.
Here's the full code snippet:

```js
const input = {
    short: 'en',
    element: {
        'dsdsea-22dada-2ffgd-xxada-eeee': { name: 'test name', comment: 'test comment' },
        'adad2a-dda13-dsdad-wwwwd-adaxx': { name: 'name 2' },
    },
};

function format(data = {}) {
    const { short = '', element = {} } = data;

    let result = Object.keys(element).map((key) => {
        return Object.values(element[key]).map((value) => ({ short, key, value }));
    });

    result = result.flat();

    return result;
}

const result = format(input);
console.log(result)
```

this prints:

```json
[
    {
        "short": "en",
        "key": "dsdsea-22dada-2ffgd-xxada-eeee",
        "value": "test name"
    },
    {
        "short": "en",
        "key": "dsdsea-22dada-2ffgd-xxada-eeee",
        "value": "test comment"
    },
    {
        "short": "en",
        "key": "adad2a-dda13-dsdad-wwwwd-adaxx",
        "value": "name 2"
    }
]
```

Comment: That is not the expected output.

Comment: It is exactly the same as the example he gave. Can you elaborate on what's wrong with it exactly?

Comment: You'll note the OP's result has three elements in the array...

Comment: I see, You're right.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const data = {short: 'en',element: {'dsdsea-22dada-2ffgd-xxada-eeee': {name: 'test name',comment: 'test comment'},'adad2a-dda13-dsdad-wwwwd-adaxx': {name: 'name 2'}}}

const result = Object
  .entries(data.element)
  .reduce((a, [key, obj]) => [
    ...a,
    ...Object
      .values(obj)
      .map(value => ({
        ...{
          short: data.short,
          key
        },
        value
      }))
  ], [])

console.log(result)
```